# How do i can call method of interface in java and get some return?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm creating my java-library. I want to implement same thing as in Spring Data. I can't insert code, because it too much code.
There is good example of code, in Spring Data

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.java

How can I implement same interface in my java library?
If i write, for example:

```
   MongoRepository.saveAll();
```

Then interface automatically executes that method, i can't understand. How did Spring Data do it?
How are we calling method of interface and getting a return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How did Spring Data do it?

With magic. While repositories *are* interfaces, during runtime an implementation is built and methods generated (also method names parsed so you get those automatic `findFooByBar()` custom generated methods).

So if you want to do the same thing yourself, you'll need to learn about bytecode generation and many many other things.

Comment: Am i need Learning more about bytecode generation and that's all? Bytecode generation in Java or in common  bytecode generation?

Comment: @МирославСтрельбицкий well understanding the magic isn't very hard. The code is generated. If you want to *recreate* what Spring Data does, that involves a lot more understanding and skill.

Comment: What direction in java am i need digging ? Is It only bytecode or something else too?

Comment: @МирославСтрельбицкий other things too. It won't be easy. You might not be able to do it.